# How can I configure Virtual Host without restarting Apache web server?

Tags: apache, webserver, virtualhost

I created a new virtual host in apache web server and I dont want to restart Apache

Does Anybody know How can I configure VirtualHost without restarting Apache web server?

Also Is it possible to do it on windows server?

Answer (score 1):

this is not possible .... you have to restart the server to get new / changed vhost.

what you can do is: restart the server without kill any active connections by:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 -graceful [*]
```

[*] /etc/init.d/**apache2** is your executable file

Answer (score 1):

You can reload `apache2` for get affect newly changes.

```
$ sudo systemctl reload apache2
```